# Fetch value from json array key starts with @

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am trying to access the value of

> @angular/core

from json file looks like bellow

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
   "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
   "core-js": "^2.5.4",
   "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
   "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
```

the code which i have tried is

```
    def packageString = readFile("app/package.json")  // read the json file
    def parsedPackageString =  new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(packageString)

    echo "My Angular Project version $parsedPackageString.dependencies.@angular/core"
```

but it is printing all the values of dependencies

My expected result is

> "^6.1.0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only to specify property for **parsedPackageString**:

```
def parsedPackageString =  new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(packageString).dependencies.'@angular/core'
```